# If I have a method in a subclass that asks for an object of the super class, how do i distinguish both?

Tags: java, oop

What I mean by this is, if I have `A obj1 = new B(); A obj2 = new B();` I want to know how to call the same method for both objects, and also want to know how to know which object is calling the method and when:

For example, lets say my class hierarchy looks something like this:

```
abstract class A {
    public void method_1() {
        //Do something
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public boolean method_2(A obj) { 
        //Do something
    }
}
```

If I where to do `obj1.method_2(obj2);` How do I, inside `method_2()`, when I code it so both `obj1` and `obj2` call `method_1()`, distinguish which obj is calling the method?

I hope my question was clear enough.
I'm sorry in advance if my English wasn't understandable enough.

Comment: `obj1.method_2(obj2);` won't compile

Comment: *How do I [..] distinguish which obj is calling the method?* - Do you really need to? Why?

Comment: And can give an explanation to why it won't compile?

Comment: `obj1` is of type `A` which doesn't have `method_2` defined in it

Comment: @JoaoFernandes Because they are both objects of type `A`, and class `A` is not aware of `method_2`.

Comment: @BackSlash Yes I really need to do it, not once, but multiple times and in a few different methods that kinda work the same way. Why? Because I need to know I can or cannot excute some other lines of code and return a true or false depending on the result.

Comment: Just have a method that returns a boolean that says whether or not this object can execute these other lines of codes. You don't need to identify if it is one or the other, since it's telling you whether it can or not, regardless of which of the two it is.

Comment: @user7 But i though it if I defined it Like "List  l = new ArrayList<something>()" Instead of  "ArrayList al = new ArrayList<something>()" that I woud be able to do so... Is there some other way to make this work then?

Comment: "I hope my question was clear enough" totally not... "distinguish which obj is calling the method" if you do `obj1.someMethod()` then it's obj1 who is calling the method, where is your problem ? Inside the code of the method ? then call `this` and you'll get the object currently executing the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obj1 which is instance of B but references class A, won't have access to method_2
So you need to cast like this

```
((B) obj1).method_2(obj2);
```

or you can change the reference to B instead of A

```
B obj1 = new B();
```

Base reference can't call the child's method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String arg[] ) {
        A obj1 = new A() {};
        A obj2 = new B();
        B obj3 = new B();

        obj1.method_1("1 "+obj1.getClass());
        obj2.method_1("2 "+obj2.getClass());

        obj3.method_1("3 "+obj3.getClass());

        obj3.method_2(obj1);

        obj3.method_2(obj2);
    }

}


abstract class A {
    public void method_1(String className) {//Do something
        System.out.println("A.method_1() called by "+className);
    }
}


class B extends A {
    public boolean method_2(A obj) {//Do something
        super.method_1("4 "+obj.getClass());
        obj.method_1("5 "+obj.getClass());

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT create an object of class A as its abstract class. However you can create object of B and pass it in place of A in method_2(). When you call method_1() inside method_2(), you are still calling it through object of class B. Here is the test program I could write based on my understanding of your question -

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B();
        B b2 = new B();
        b.method_2(b2); //Or
        //b.method_2((A)b2);

    }

}

abstract class A {
    public void method_1() {
        System.out.println("In method_1 = " + this.getClass());

    }
}

class B extends  A {
    public boolean method_2(A a) {
        System.out.println("In method_2 = " + this.getClass());
        a.method_1();
        return false;

    }
}
```

The result is that both methods are called by object of class B. You can user getSuperClass() method to get superclass name.